# C++ if statement order

Tags: c++, performance, search, c-strings

A portion of a program needs to check if two c-strings are identical while searching though an ordered list (e.g.`{"AAA", "AAB", "ABA", "CLL", "CLZ"}`). It is feasible that the list could get quite large, so small improvements in speed are worth degradation of readability. Assume that you are restricted to C++ (please don't suggest switching to assembly). How can this be improved?

```
typedef char StringC[5];
void compare (const StringC stringX, const StringC stringY)
{
    // use a variable so compareResult won't have to be computed twice
    int compareResult = strcmp(stringX, stringY);
    if (compareResult < 0) // roughly 50% chance of being true, so check this first
    {
        // no match. repeat with a 'lower' value string
        compare(stringX, getLowerString() );
    }
    else if (compareResult > 0) // roughly 49% chance of being true, so check this next
    {
        // no match. repeat with a 'higher' value string
        compare(stringX, getHigherString() );
    }
    else // roughly 1% chance of being true, so check this last
    {
        // match
        reportMatch(stringY);
    }
}
```

You can assume that `stringX` and `stringY` are always the same length and you won't get any invalid data input.

From what I understand, a compiler will make the code so that the CPU will check the first if-statement and jump if it's false, so it would be best if that first statement is the most likely to be true, as jumps interfere with the pipeline. I have also heard that when doing a compare, a[n Intel] CPU will do a subtraction and look at the status of flags without saving the subtraction's result. Would there be a way to do the `strcmp` once, without saving the result into a variable, but still being able to check that result during the both of the first two if-statements?

Comment: I'd suggest you switch to C++ (currently you have C code with a _touch_ of C++ syntax). About that code path microoptimization: don't bother to guess, **inspect generated assembly** output (you may be surprised...) Also more often than not is **more important input pattern** (how many consecutive `< 0`?) than most common code path. Final note: if you do it in C you may want to use `memcmp` instead of `strcmp` for **fixed length strings**

Comment: *"way to do the strcmp once, without saving the result into a variable,"* Why?! `strcmp` anyways generates a result in form of `int`. A variable is already allocated for the purpose. You will not gain anything if you don't store in `compareResult`. Your present code seems good to go, should you choose C style syntax.

Comment: `compare` is the wrong level at which to improve the runtime of your program. You mentioned that it's an ordered sequence, so a much better approach would be not to do a liner search over your sequence (which I guess) but rather a binary search. Since you're using C++, you could use an appropriate container (say: `std::set<std::string>`) which takes care of such algorithmic improvements for you.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, you cannot do a binary search, basically because you don't know where the equal strings will be in the string space. You must do a linear search, but only comparing each string *with the next in the array*, as you know the array is sorted, you know that if two equal strings are in the array, they must be together.

Comment: @LuisColorado I don't get it - my understanding is that the OP wants to test whether some C string is a member of some other (ordered) set of C strings. To do this, he's implementing a `compare` function which compares two strings *and* which then attempts to select the next string to compare with. My comment is that this seems to be the basic problem of testing for membership in a sorted sequence of values, and that problem has been solved already -- there is no separate `compare` function needed at all.

Comment: @frerichRaabe, The OP says *A portion of a program needs to check if two c-strings are identical while searching though an ordered list*  I interpret **two c-strings of the ordered list are identical to each other**  or the same as if somebody has put twice the same string in the list.

Comment: @LuisColorado It may well be that I did not read the question correctly, seems I'm not alone with my interpretation though given how many suggestions there are for binary searches. In case the OP meant what you describe, two equal C strings in an ordered list would be subsequent elements of that list, so it seems to be one only needs to check if there are any two subsequent elements in the list which are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::binary_search` may help:

```
bool cstring_less(const char (&lhs)[4], const char (&rhs)[4])
{
    return std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(lhs), std::end(lhs),
                                        std::begin(rhs), std::end(rhs));
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    const char cstrings[][4] = {"AAA", "AAB", "ABA", "CLL", "CLZ"};
    const char lookFor[][4] = {"BBB", "ABA", "CLS"};

    for (const auto& s : lookFor)
    {
        if (std::binary_search(std::begin(cstrings), std::end(cstrings),
                               s, cstring_less))
        {
            std::cout << s << " Found.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/VF13zS)

Comment: ...ordered list jarod. Can be done in linear time, or am I misunderstanding the question? are we looking for duplicates or finding a candidate?

Comment: @RichardHodges: I propose a logarithm solution (in `cstring_less` calls), which is better than linear time.

Comment: I think I read the question differently to you. I was thinking it was asking to check for duplicates. I think you're right.

Comment: Just comparing each element to the next, solves the problem of finding the repeated elements.

Comment: @Jarod42, you cannot, as repeated strings can appear anywhere in the list of ordered strings.  You have the only option of doing a linear search to find them.  What you know is that two equal strings, case of existing, will be together in an ordered array.  so the problem is linear `O(N)`.  The only improvement is to calculate hashes (not a strong improvement) and has been posted as an answer already.

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect, there's nothing that directs you to the position of the equal strings, then there's no chance to do a binary search.  The matching strings can be anywhere in the list.  The only thing you know (as the list is ordered) is that if two strings are equal, they must be together in the ordered list.

Comment: @LuisColorado: We understand the OP's problem differently. You're looking for duplicated strings whereas I check if ordered list contains a specific element.

Comment: @LuisColorado If this answer is indeed completely incorrect, I do wonder why the OP accepted it.

Comment: Believe me, I wonder also.  But the OP is not the judge here.

Answer (score 0):

I think using hash tables can improve the speed of comparison drastically. Also, if your program is multithreaded, you can find some useful hash tables in intel thread building blocks library. For example, tbb::concurrent_unordered_map has the same api as std::unordered_map

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I'm afraid not, not drastically at least.  If two strings are identical in an already ordered array, you have only to compare each element to the next, so you do only two comparisons for each element (one with the previous element, another with the next)  If you hash all, you have to calculate the hash of each element and, in case of comparison (of hashes) results in a match, you have to make one comparison:  Result: you calculate hashes and compare hashes instead of comparing strings.  Hash calculation is cheaper than string comparison, but the algorithm is not *drastically improved*.

Comment: Of course, if you use a hash table (this is not the case) you have only to search the hash lists that have more than one entry (but again you need to search linearly the hash array) and then compare entries (to discard hash collissions, this is, *different* entries which hash to the same value)  So this is not the expected improvement using hash values associated with each array entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to compare all the strings to each other you'll get in a `O(N*(N-1))` problem.  The best thing, as you have stated the lists can grow large, is to sort them (`qsort` algorithm has `O(N*log(N))`) **and then compare each element with the next one in the list**, which adds a new `O(N)` giving up to `O(N*log(N))` total complexity.  As you have the list *already ordered*, you can just traverse it (making the thing `O(N)`), comparing each element with the next.  An example, valid in C and C++ follows:

```
for(i = 0; i < N-1; i++)  /* one comparison less than the number of elements */
    if (strcmp(array[i], array[i+1]) == 0) 
        break;
if (i < N-1) {  /* this is a premature exit from the loop, so we found a match */
    /* found a match, array[i] equals array[i+1] */
} else { /* we exhausted al comparisons and got out normally from the loop */
    /* no match found */
}
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged with [c++], you could just use [`std::adjacent_find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/adjacent_find/).